# Why does this C function take a pointer-to-pointer as a parameter?

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm trying to understand this C code from a simple priority queue, especially - why does it need the `struct qnode **first` part:

```
int quedel(struct qnode **first, struct qnode **last, int *prio, int *val) {
 struct qnode *tmp = NULL;

 if((NULL == *last) && (*last == *first)) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Empty queue.....\n");
  return -1;
 }

 *val = (*first)->data, *prio = (*first)->prio;
 tmp = *first, *first = (*first)->next;

 if(*last == tmp)
  *last = (*last)->next;
 free(tmp);

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since C doesn't have pass-by-reference, only pass-by-value, this approach is the only way to make this assignment:

```
*first = (*first)->next;
```

visible to the caller.

(If `first` were just a single pointer, and we wrote `first = first->next`, then the code that calls this function wouldn't see the modification.)

Comment: C *has* pass-by-reference, which you implement with pointers. "Pass-by-reference" is a concept, not a specific programming language construct. By contrast, C++ also allows passing-by-reference, either via pointers or via a native reference type. Java on the other hand has [no passing by reference at all](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm).

Comment: @KerrekSB: I disagree; pass-by-value and pass-by-reference are a matter of language semantics. C and Java both have only pass-by-value, though both offer mechanisms to emulate pass-by-reference semantics (in C, you can pass a pointer; in Java, you can pass a mutable wrapper object).

Comment: @KerrekSB: By the way, the page that you link to agrees with me; it says, for example, "Java is *strictly* pass-by-value, exactly as in C."

Comment: Reference semantics means that you can write a function that modifies a variable in the caller scope. In C you can do that, for *any* variable, and it just so happens that the way to do this (pointers) is already part of the existing type system. I linked that article mainly for its "litmus test" about the general ability to write a *swap* function, which you *can* do in C (`void swap(T *, T *); swap(&x, &y);`). Java may let you pass some sort of referential information under certain conditions, but not generally.

Comment: @KerrekSB: No, reference semantics means that a function's parameters are aliases for variables in the caller scope. In C, as you know, `void swap(T, T); swap(x, y)` will not swap `x` and `y`. (And Java, by the way, lets you pass referential information under *all* conditions, by creating a mutable wrapper class, or by passing a single-element array. It's not as convenient as C's pointer approach, IMHO, and you can't use it to wrap an existing variable, but people seem to find it less confusing, so I guess it's an even trade.)

Answer (score 2):

Since the queue itself is handled via pointers (to `struct qnode`s), and since you want `quedel` to have reference semantics for its `first` and `last` elements, you use the usual C idiom of implementing reference semantics by passing a pointer to the thing you want to refer to -- and a pointer to a pointer to a `struct qnode` is, well, a double pointer.

The point of the `quedel` function is to modify the actual variable inside the caller's scope, since it removes the head of the queue and changes the caller's original head pointer to a new pointer to the new head (or tail, or whichever way round this thing goes):

```
{
    struct qnode * q = new_queue();  // or whatever

    add_lots_of_elements(q);         // fine; the head doesn't change,
                                     // only its contents do

    quedel(&q);                      // now q is something else!
}
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much! It's clicking!